# ElasticSearch order by _score

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I order the results by `_score`?

I can't figure out how to calculate the score for each result, also :)

I managed to write this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "type_licitatie": "3"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "tip_sursa": "5"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "country_id": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "industry_id": "3"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }        
          }
        }
      },
      "script_score" : {
        "script": "(doc['country_id'].values=1) + (doc['industry_id'].values=3)"
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added sample documents, mapping and what's not working for you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a 'curl recreation' as described here: https://www.elasticsearch.org/help/ . The default order should be score descending, but I imagine you are trying to sort based on a score calculated by your script?

Comment: In the first query all documents will have the same score. Since they are either matched or not.

Comment: In the 2 example you missing the "sort" `"sort": { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}`. You can check my **Function score** in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106110/elasticsearch-sort-by-dynamic-price)